# Convert Notepad to mindmap

Tags: note-taking, mind-mapping

I often end up writing my notes in notepad++ . I cant seem to find time to convert all the notes to mindmaps. 
Is there any software that can import these notes to a mindmap? Preferably for Windows. I use Linux too, so its fine if its Linux/web/Android too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net) can paste text if the text is indented by tabs or spaces (it seems to auto-detect the number of spaces, I tried with 3 and 4 spaces).

It can't import a root node, however. If you have a text file like

```
root
    branch 2
        branch 2.1
        item 2.2
    branch 1
        sub-branch 1.1
            1.1.1
            1.1.2
        leaf 1.2
```

You can copy everything except "root", open a new mind map in Freemind and paste the text. The result will be

[image: Freemind from clipboard]

Freemind is free (GPL2), works fine on Windows and there are instructions for [Linux](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/FreeMind_on_Linux).

Comment: Given the same structure of the notes, [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) will also load the text fine but small amount of adjustment with the root would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Mindjet's [Mind Manager](https://www.mindjet.com/mindmanager/) is the commercial equivalent to FreeMind, starting at ~350 USD. If you like to have commercial support or you benefit from the additional features, this might be preferred.

Similar to Freemind, Mind Manager can paste from clipboard if the text is indented by spaces or tabs (like Freemind), also with the same limitation that it can't import a root node.

```
root
   branch 2
      branch 2.1
      item 2.2
   branch 1
      sub-branch 1.1
         1.1.1
         1.1.2
      leaf 1.2
```

If you copy everything except "root" you get:

[image: Result from paste operation in Mind Manager]

I run it on Windows (7 SP1 x64); I couldn't find information about Linux on the website.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you structure your notes in a restructured text format you could write a bit of [python](http://python.org) using [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) to parse the structure and then [mekk.xmind](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mekk.xmind) to create an [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) map from it.